# MSSQL and AD in a Docker Container

Tags: docker, sql

I am attempting to use Active Directory authentication with SQL Server on Linux running inside the official MSFT Docker container for MSSQL (https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server)

I am in the midst of working through this tutorial, but I heard from a coworker that it wouldn't work in a container. He did not say why. He did say which particular step he was doubtful about ('Join SQL Server host to AD domain')

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-2017

Is there any reason why I can't complete the 'Join SQL Server host to AD domain' step if I'm using containers?

Comment: Were you successful, and if so how did you test it, perhaps with some kind of _impersonation_ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You absolutely can do this.  However, you will need to make sure that the following is happening:

- Setup the Docker host on the MSSQL computer in such a way that it can reach the AD server.  Using a [bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) may help (especially if you are using Docker for Windows).  If using Docker Toolkit you may need to look into a solution like [port forwarding](http://woshub.com/port-forwarding-in-windows/).
- [Commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) your configuration changes to a new Docker image.  This will allow you to move the MSSQL container to a new computer or even run it with Kubernetes/Orchestration tooling.
- Map your MSSQL container to a [Volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) for persistence.  Otherwise the data in the container will be eliminated between container restarts.

Answer (score 0):

As per the attached document, I see no issue with executing this task.
The one thing that you need to do update your container with a configuration that is needed to reach AD server.

That means those changes can be done in live SQL server container and committed or add to a Dockerfile and build.